# Target attribute when performing redirects in Google App Engine (Python)

Tags: python, facebook, google-app-engine, href

I am trying to implement Facebook Login in my Canvas App using "Manually Build a Login Flow". To implement this successfully, I have to redirect to the Facebook authentication url with target = "_top" parameter, basically the following redirect:

`<a href="https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id={app-id}&redirect_uri={redirect-uri}" target="_top">Redirect here </a>`

I know we can use `self.redirect({url})` to perform redirects in GAE, but am unable to find how can we set up a target as in the above html code.

Please help me out.

Answer (score 0):

Target just defines where the browser window will open the page. If the `<a>` (hereafter "link") is in an iframe, the browser will open the link in the highest level of the frameset (as a regular page). This is important for oauth links since iframes have certain restrictions which break the needed flow of requests.

You'll be fine doing a regular redirect, assuming that the link the user clicked to get to the redirecting handler was itself an `<a>` element that is either not running in an iframe or has `target="_top"` if so.